# php curl response blank randomly

Tags: php, networking, curl

We are implementing api with curl.
We send xml request and get xml response. 
Some cases randomly  we did not receive any response. 
When we co-ordinated with api provider they told there is no request hit on there server in case of blank response.

How we will know,  its not hit on api provider server. 
Is there any header response ?

Comment: Use a packet sniffer tool like Wireshark to see if it there is traffic going out, and then you will also see if you get an ACK back

Comment: curl_error and currl_errno and if errno != 0 save it and see what happens

Comment: @jaques sorry, We could not manage at server level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some troubleshooting cURL options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

**Get results**

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
$skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
$responseHeader = substr($data,0,$skip);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$requestHeader = $info['request_header'];
$info = var_export($info,true);
echo "<pre>$requestHeader \n\n $responseHeader\n\n $info \n $data";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get curl error and errorno.Use this

```
var_dump(curl_errno($ch));
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

Comment: We are adding this in log.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some code to handle response
I don't know how your code looks like but it may be as simple as this

```
// add this line before curl_exec
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl);
// do this before closing curl connection
curl_close($curl);
```

and here is some more details about curl_getinfo
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

Add to your curl query:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

curl will be more verbose

```
curl_getinfo($ch);
```

can also be helpfull